# 2SLS Regression, 1 Instrument effecting more than one explanatory variable?

Tags: regression, econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

So in my situation I have my dependent variable **Log Income** my Instrument **Diabetes** and my supposedly endogenous explanatory variable **Reads Nutri**. Where things start to get confusing for me is that there are two other explanatory variables in my model that should also be correlated with my instrument **BMI** and **health related work limitations**. If **BMI** positively effects **Diabetes** and **Diabetes** positively effects **health related work limitations**, than should **BMI** and **health related work limitations** also be instrumented in my 2SLS regression? how do I now go about preforming my 2SLS IV regression?

Comment: What is your structural model?  Is it $lnincome=\beta_0 + \beta_1ReadsNutri+\beta_2BMI+\beta_3Limit+\epsilon$ or should $BMI$ and $HealthLimit$ be included in the *structural* model as well?

Comment: It seems to me that a rudimentary conceptual model showing the hypothesized relationships would help clarify the question.  The bigger concern is: are there other factors affecting $Diabetes$ besides $BMI$ that you need to account for in the model?  Are there other factors affecting $HealthLimit$ *and* $lnincome$ as yet not accounted for in the model?

Comment: @marquisdecarabas, my model is: 'Log Income' = b0 + b1*'Black' + b2*'Male' + b3*'Highest Grade' + b4*'Health Limitations' + b5*''Height' + b6*'Reads Nutri' + b7*'Maried-ish' +b8*'Age' + b9*'Age squared' + b10*'Number of Jobs' + b11*'Experience (weeks)' + b12* 'Experience (weeks) squared' + b14'BMI' . what do you think?

Comment: First and foremost, I'd be skeptical that BMI is a valid instrument. There's a million reasons [why obesity could affect income](https://doi.org/10.1111/joes.12458).

Answer (score 0):

It is fine that your other variables of the structural equation, *BMI and health-related work limitations.* be correlated with the instrument. If they are not your research interest, it will even be fine for the variables to be endogenous.

Additionally, I believe you could not have more endogenous variables than instruments. So if you are performing 2SLS in STATA:

```
ivregress Log_Income Controls (Reads_Nutri= Diabetes), robust
```

where Controls are just all the controls you have.